# Do I need to install MonogDB on my PC in order to use it with NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am in process of learning NodeJS and now diving into database stuff and want to learn MongoDB with Mongoose package.

I am having some difficulties with installing MongoDB on my PC since it is 32bit system and I become curious do I actually need to install it on my PC in order to use it?

Or can I just do "npm install mongodb" and use it within my sample project and then also install "mnogoose", or it is required to have MongoDB installed on my PC as well?

I would be very thankful if someone could help me and explain process a bit. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need to install Mongo.

'npm install mongodb' only installs the mongo driver.

Comment: Alight, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb from npm install is just, according to the official description: 
"The official MongoDB driver for Node.js. Provides a high-level API on top of mongodb-core that is meant for end users."

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb

So you will still need to install the MongoDB server in order to use it within your project. The mongodb package just allows you to access mongodb server from within node.

Comment: But what if i decide to deploy my project on Heroku? Is MongoDB already installed there and my mongoose package will do do job ?

Comment: @nikola1970 You can install MongoDB on Heroku https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mongolab and then you can use mongoose to access the database

Comment: Thanks @Prince John :)